Web part to filter planner plans based on the Assigned To user?
Web part to filter planner plans based on the Assigned To user?
We have a Teams which contain around 40++ planner plans. The managers are facing troubles when they want to see all the tasks from all the planner plans assigned to certain user. Currently to do this, they need to go to each individual plan and do the filter, is there any built-in or using sharepoint web parts to be able to filter all the tasks from different plans based on the assigned to user?
can we for example benefit from modern search web part to achieve this? or any other web parts?
